# Variance and covariance of a measurement given a benchmark measurement

Tags: sampling, covariance-matrix, ratio

I have a set of 20 measurements
$$(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{19}, x_{20}) $$
in which 18 of the measurements are a sort of benchmark, and two measurements are special, although obeying the same sources of errors as the first 18 measurements. E.g., say that I am measuring the size of 18 balls that in theory have the same size, and then I have two other balls with significantly different sizes where I apply the same measurement method.

In the end, what I need, are the following two ratios:
$$
r_1= \frac{x_{19}}{\bar{x}} , ~~~~~~ r_2=\frac{x_{20}}{\bar{x}}
$$
where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of the first **18** measurements.

Now, I also need the covariance matrix for $r_1$ and $r_2$, that is,
$$ 
C_{r1r2} = \begin{pmatrix} var(r_1) & covar(r_1,r_2) \\ covar(r_2,r_1) & var(r_2) \end{pmatrix}
$$

I estimate the variance of $\bar{x}$ numerically from the first 18 measurements. I then assume that the variance of measurements $x_{19}$ and $x_{20}$ is the same. I then use propagation of error to get the variance for $r_1$ and $r_2$, e.g.:

$$ 
\sigma_{r1}^2 = r_1^2\big( \frac{\sigma^2_{\bar{x}}}{18 \bar{x}^2}+\frac{\sigma^2_{x_{19}}}{x_{19}^2}\big) = r_1^2\sigma^2_{\bar{x}}(\frac{1}{18 \bar{x}^2}+\frac{1}{x_{19}^2})
$$

And similarly for $x_{20}$. How do I get the covariances from this?
Is there something wrong with my method here?